# Update/populate DataGrid with data asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, wpfdatagrid

I have checked some of topics and google but can't find proper solution.
I want to make WPF application to download Items information to DataGrid (items columns) with TextBox (item name) using RestApi.

The code is correct and work but there's a problem with async updating DataGrid.

```
DataTable dt;
public DataTable Dt { get => dt; set { dt = value; dataGridItems.DataContext = Dt.DefaultView; } }

private async void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //buttonSearch.IsEnabled = false;
    rest = new RestClass(ClientId, ClientSecret);

    Task T = Task.Run(() => SearchItem(rest, textBoxProductName.Text));

    T.ContinueWith((t) =>
       {
           dataGridItems.DataContext = Dt.DefaultView;
           //buttonSearch.IsEnabled = true;
       }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Above code with small changes (dataGridItems.DataBinding) worked in WinForms without any problems but I can't make it work in WPF application.

```
private void SearchItem(RestClass Rest, string ItemName)
{
    try
    {
        var x = Rest.GetTokenJ().Result;
        ItemsOffersWPF.Rootobject searchResponse = Rest.requestSearchItem(ItemName);
        GetItemsCollection(searchResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    //dataGridItems.DataContext = Dt.DefaultView;
}
```

I have tried Invoke, InvokeAsync but it makes UI irresponsible which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Guessing, that SearchItem() is the method which will freeze your UI. All you got to do is to call it on Background Task. And when it is ready i.e. In ContinueWith in your code - Call Dispatcher.Invoke() with the changes that you want to do. Make sure the Dispatcher instance you get if for the Control being updated.

Comment: Another guess: Your `ButtonSearch_Click` contains the `async` Keyword, so you may be missing the `await` before the `Task.Run(() =>...);`

Comment: tried await before Task.Run but it gives error that UI is updating from another thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to you, I finally found solution. It's not perfect but works well.
The problem was propably updating DataTable (Dt property) inside GetItemsCollection method and using textBoxProductName.Text inside await SearchItem function.

```
// its useless now
//DataTable Dt { get => dt; set { dt = value; dataGridAllegro.DataContext = Dt.DefaultView; } } 
private async void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   buttonSearch.IsEnabled = false;
   var productName = textBoxProductName.Text; // get Text value before using Task!
   await Task.Run(() => SearchItem(productName));
   dataGridItems.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
   buttonSearch.IsEnabled = true;
}     

private async void SearchItem(string ProductName)
{
   try
   {
      var x = rest.GetTokenJ().Result;
      ItemsOffersWPF.Rootobject searchResponse = rest.requestSearchItem(ProductName);
      GetItemsCollection(searchResponse); // inside update dt not property DataTable Dt { get => dt; set { dt = value; dataGridAllegro.DataContext = Dt.DefaultView; } }
   // = exception using another thread UI
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use await instead of T.ContinueWith

```
    await Task.Run(() => SearchItem(rest, textBoxProductName.Text));
    dataGridItems.DataContext = Dt.DefaultView;
```

anything after the "await" will be executed as soon as the Task has finished running.

Comment: It gives error regarding changing UI elements from other thread
bellow works but freeze
await Task.Run(() => dataGridItems.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { SearchItem(rest, textBoxProductName.Text); buttonSearch.IsEnabled = true; }));

Comment: Nothing in SearchItem(...) or after the await is allowed to manipulate properties of UiElements, because WPF does not allow making changes to properties of UiElements from a background thread (Which you do need, if do not want blocking of the UI). You'll have to work with binding here.

Comment: He should be looking at binding and MVVM but no, you don't HAVE to work with binding. Pass the string into the task and whatever rest is as a parameter. Add a class with both rest and the search string as properties so you have one object or capture them if you particularly want inline code.  You could also make searchitem a task and return the datatable from it.

Comment: @Tim Rooney Ok i understand your point. I have DataTable binded to Grid which is updated inside SearchItem. How use binding properly? I tried ro remove all UI changes but still error